# Select current date with PHP

Tags: php, date

This is really driving me crazy, so please help.

I have this code as shown below, it displays a list of dates for the next 7 days.

Things i want the code achieve.

1. Display "Today and "Tomorrow" instead of the corresponding date.
2. Once a date is selected add "current" class, this way it is highlighted with a different color.
3. "Today" should be selected by default when the page is first loaded.

The code below achieve this requirements

```
<?php

$today = date("d-m-Y", strtotime('today')); 
$tomorrow = date("d-m-Y", strtotime('tomorrow')); 

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$today.'">'.(($_GET['date'] == $today) ? '<span class="current"' . '>Today</span>' : 'Today').'</a></li>'; 

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$tomorrow.'">'.(($_GET['date'] == $tomorrow) ? '<span class="current"' . '>Tomorrow</span>' : 'Tomorrow').'</a></li>'; 

for ($time = strtotime('+2 days'), $i=0; $i < 5; $time = strtotime('+1 days', $time), $i++) {$date = date("d-m-Y", $time);

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$date.'">'.(($_GET['date'] == $date) ? '<span class="current">' : '') . date("D jS", $time) . ((isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date'] == $date) ? '</span>' : '') . "</a></li>";}

?>
```

However recently i needed to change the formating of the date from d-m-Y to Y-m-d

As result of this my third requirement the one about "Today" been selected by default no longer works.

```
<?php

$today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today')); 
$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow')); 

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$today.'">'.(($_GET['date'] == $today) ? '<span class="current"' . '>Today</span>' : 'Today').'</a></li>'; 

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$tomorrow.'">'.(($_GET['date'] == $tomorrow) ? '<span class="current"' . '>Tomorrow</span>' : 'Tomorrow').'</a></li>'; 

for ($time = strtotime('+2 days'), $i=0; $i < 5; $time = strtotime('+1 days', $time), $i++) {$date = date("Y-m-d", $time);

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$date.'">'.(($_GET['date'] == $date) ? '<span class="current">' : '') . date("D jS", $time) . ((isset($_GET['date']) && $_GET['date'] == $date) ? '</span>' : '') . "</a></li>";}

?>
```

Can someone please help with this.

Thanks in advance

I have this Now

But I'm afraid it doesn't add the class on page load.
So "Today" is not highlight by default.

Have I messed something up?

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['date'])){

$gdate = $_GET['date'];
}

else{

$gdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today')); //Or whatever arbitrary date you want.

}
$today = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today')); 
$tomorrow = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('tomorrow')); 

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$today.'">'.(($gdate == $today) ? '<span class="current"' . '>Today</span>' : 'Today').'</a></li>'; 

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$tomorrow.'">'.(($gdate == $tomorrow) ? '<span class="current"' . '>Tomorrow</span>' : 'Tomorrow').'</a></li>'; 

for ($time = strtotime('+2 days'), $i=0; $i < 5; $time = strtotime('+1 days', $time), $i++) {$date = date("Y-m-d", $time);

echo '
<li><a href="?date='.$date.'">'.(($gdate == $date) ? '<span class="current">' : '') . date("D jS", $time) . ((isset($gdate) && $gdate == $date) ? '</span>' : '') . "</a></li>";}

?>
```

Comment: What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is `$_GET['date']` populated with?

Comment: Hi Pekka, Well I want to resolve the problem created by chnaging the date format.

Comment: $_GET['date'] = the current date. For example it currently has the value of 2011-01-08

Comment: Because $_GET['date'] is "not set" when it the page initialy loads the class is not been apllied. If I can figure out someway of applying this class. I will resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, the problem is in $_GET['date'] not being set then, right?

What you're gonna have to do is don't use $_GET['date'] in the logic.  Do something like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['date']))
{
    $gdate = $_GET['date'];
}else{
    $gdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('today')); //Or whatever arbitrary date you want.
}
```

Then you use $gdate in the logic.  That way, if $_GET['date'] is set, it will use it, otherwise it will use today's date.  By the way, you don't have to use strtotime to get today's date, just `date("Y-m-d");` will get it because the second argument for date is defaulted to the current time.

Comment: Hello Phonix. I have tryied to incorpate your solution but I'm having problem making it work. Can you please show me how I would add it to my original code. Thanks again.

Comment: Add it above the declarations of `$today` and `$tomorrow`, and replace all instances of `$_GET['date']` with `$gdate`, except the `$_GET['date']`s in the code above.